# Kubernete-dashboard is not deploying

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to install kubernete-dashboard on my cluster.
I am running the below command:-

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

Error:-

> Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": RoleBinding in version "v1" cannot be handled as a RoleBinding: no kind "RoleBinding" is registered for version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1"

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What is the version of your cluster? could you run following commands and update the questions ?  `kubectl version` and `kubectl api-versions` thanks

Comment: kubectl version: 
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"269f928217957e7126dc87e6adfa82242bfe5b1e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-07-03T15:31:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"269f928217957e7126dc87e6adfa82242bfe5b1e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-07-03T15:31:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: kubectl api-versions: 
apps/v1beta1
authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
autoscaling/v1
batch/v1
certificates.k8s.io/v1alpha1
extensions/v1beta1
policy/v1beta1
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1
storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
v1

Comment: I think you need to update the client as well as the server since you are having 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a Service account in your cluster and a user administrator: 
Use this file...

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
```

### Create user

Create sample user (if using RBAC - on by default on new installs with kops / kubeadm):

```
kubectl create -f sample-user.yaml
```

### Get login token:

```
kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep admin-user
kubectl -n kube-system describe secret admin-user-token-<id displayed by previous command>
```

### Login to dashboard

Apply kubectl proxy

Go to http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#!/login

### Login with user and pass

kubectl config view

Login: admin
Password: the password that is listed in ~/.kube/config (open file in editor and look for "password: ..."

Choose for login token and enter the login token from the previous step

### Login with minikube

minikube dashboard --url